# How do I run a mysql script on my dev machine

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL in a docker container on my macbook pro.  I would like to restore a database using a command line.  I have 3 scripts that are thousands of lines long and would like to run them from.  I my been doing this using Sequel Pro to connect to localhost:3306 but it does not handle the large scripts very well.

Comment: You mount a local path inside the container using the `docker run -v` option, then `docker exec` into the container and run `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker has `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` as a path from which it initializes. This can contain SQL files and scripts.

```
docker run -v /path/to/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d \
-e MYSQL_USER=dbuser \
-e MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbpass \
-e MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sosecret \
mysql
```

ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: This looks like you are doing more than just running the above. Are you using compose? Include details by editing your question or asking a new question.